# How to use ament_lint_common's ament_copyright on a "BSD" licensed-package such as geographic_info

Tags: ros2, ament

## Problem Description

I have a code contribution to the [geographic_info package](https://github.com/ros-geographic-info/geographic_info/tree/ros2). That package says the license in the `package.xml` is "BSD".

That is not a valid SPDX identifier.

What should I do to make this a "Tier 1" package, when Tier 1 packages are required to use ament_lint_common?

There is no way to get `colcon test` to pass with `ament_lint_common` enabled because "BSD" is not a valid or recognized license.

## Considered Workarounds

### Add license text for BSD0 to the headers

This doesn't work because only bsd2, bsd_2clause and bsd_3clause are supported:

```
$ ament_copyright --list-licenses
apache2: Apache License, Version 2.0
boost1: Boost Software License - Version 1.0
bsd2: BSD License 2.0
bsd_2clause: 2-Clause BSD License
bsd_3clause: 3-Clause BSD License
gplv3: GNU General Public License 3.0
lgplv3: GNU Lesser General Public License 3.0
mit: MIT License
mit0: MIT-0 License
```

Furthermore, it's super confusing to me because these identifiers are not the same as the [SPDX identifiers](https://spdx.org/licenses/BSD-2-Clause.html).

For BSD2, SPDX identifies it with `BSD-2-Clause`, not `bsd_2clause`.

### Add a top level "LICENSE" file in the root of the repo

This has no effect

### Set AMENT_LINT_AUTO_FILE_EXCLUDE to the new C++ files I added

If you do that, and they are the only files in the package, then cppcheck fails because it found 0 files to lint

### Disable ament_lint_copyright

This does not appear to be possible.

### Only ignore files for ament_lint_copyright

THis does not appear to be possible.

### Relicense the package

I emailed the original author, but haven't gotten a response yet. It seems difficult to relicense.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code it looks like the licenses in the files are BSD-3-Clause.

The package.xml is a summary of the licenses in the package. To that end you can update it to be more specific. We used BSD as the name before SPDX was a common standard.

You need to look at the code and find out what the license(s) are and make sure that they are summarized correctly in the package.xml and the LICENSE file is a newer standard way to share it too.

Adding SPDX support for the linter strings would be great too. But I'm pretty sure BSD0 isn't correct.

Comment: I still can't get this to work. ament_copyright fix doesn't seem to autofix files with a license of "BSD-3-Clause".

Answer (score -1):

You can write an extension to `ament_lint_copyright` using Python's entry points that will include the BSD0 copyright text, and any other license text you want. I did it a couple of years back for some proprietary licenses, but I no longer have access to that code to post an example.

Comment: Ah yea, another option is to contribute to `ament_cmake`. I figured I was using the tool wrong. I'm surprised it doesn't support more licenses. Do you have any clue why no one upstreams their hooks?

Comment: For us, it was to support internal licenses so there was very low incentive in the company to share that. Hopefully the SPDX support makes such an extension necessary only in the cases like mine, which is probably worth the pain imposed on proprietary implementations.